# how can I parsing json with two arrays in javascript?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

how can I parsing json with two arrays in javascript?
I know when there is just one array in json I can use jet json. The problem is that there is an array inside another array, how i can parse this json file in jquery? what is the code to parse json with 2arrays in JavaScript?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c']];

jQuery.each(arr, function (key, value) {
    jQuery.each(value, function (innerKey, innerVal) {
       // Do something with your values here.
    });
});
```

Is that what you are looking for? Hope that helps.